# Cache password in JavaScript for later use, securely

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, passwords

We're currently developing a web-application that needs to decrypt data stored on the server with the user's password. The main goal is to not ask the user again for his password so the idea is, after login, store the password in a global JavaScript variable to have access to it later on when downloading and decrypting the files. Somehow I don't like the notion of keeping the password around, but from a marketing perspective the higher priority is convenience.

Am I just being paranoid or is this a possible security problem? If this could be a security problem, how can I implement this in a safe way that does not interfere with the convenience factor?

**edit**

Data is encrypted on the client when uploading and shall be decrypted on the client after the download. The user's password is stored on the server hashed with SHA-256.

Comment: You want to have the password available offline?

Comment: Never, ever, ever store a password in JavaScript, a cookie, or localstorage.

Comment: It would probably be better to store a token generated with the password. What are you using for the server?

Comment: Something that might be an enlightening read while we are on the topic: http://torrentfreak.com/new-browser-tool-claims-to-reveal-mega-user-master-key-130903/ . Basically how Mega stores the user master key in localStorage.

Comment: Do not store it in javascript. If it's possible to exploit a XSS vulnerability in your site, the password could be sent to the attacker.

Comment: Can you give more information on the crypting method? When are the data encrypted? Just before they are sent to the user?

Comment: Is it possible to keep the password on the server (preferably encrypted) then grab it from there based on the users session? It's still far from ideal, but storing it client side would just be horrible >_<

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Session variables? They are much more secure.

And if you need to stick to client side JavaScript, I think you can store them in cookies.

However, I'm not sure what you are really trying to achieve for your app.

Comment: The cookies have the same security level than a simple javascript variable. It is really easy to read them, for the user, or for a hacker who would have succeeded an XSS attack.

Comment: Exactly, cookies are not secure, and I never said they are secure. But you shouldn't be storing the password anywhere in the first place.

Please read the Answer thoroughly before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating an object that handles the decryption that has private access to the password, via the module pattern?

http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Comment: It doesn't secure the process. This only helps the developpers to have variables less accessible.

Comment: When you say 'less accessible', are you saying that the variable is still able to be obtained by code other than that declared within the closure?  If so, and for my own personal enrichment, I would like to know how?

Comment: In javascript, every variable is global. I don't know how your library really works, but you can be sure that the data it contains can be available with another name.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the variable data would be accessible by another name?  My understanding is that a closure variable is inaccessible outside of its closure, so I'd be very interested if this was not true.

Comment: Open up developer tools and you can see and access anything in your client-side code.

Comment: Right, but those are *global* variables, not *closure* variables.  I'm not advocating for storing the password as a global.

Comment: @JacobJohnson Scope does not matter.  Again, **anything** client-side is visible.  You are confusing scope with security.  Closures only prevent programmatic access to internals of the closure.  You can still open up your developer tools and inspect every variable inside the closure.

Comment: I agree that I can place a breakpoint in the closure, and thereby inspect the contents, but is this something that code, other than my own, would be able to do within a browser?  Could a malicious script perform the same act, or is this merely due to the fact that I, the current user, have access to eternal browser capabilities, namely the ability to debug the code?

Comment: It's very simple, really.  You should never store sensitive data client-side since it is fairly easily accessible to anyone.  If you have a closure that decrypts this password, anyone will be able to see the password if they simply open up their developer tools and set a breakpoint.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered the threat in meatspace of second individual accessing that computer.  Thank you for your explanation.